# How to convert a generated word document DOCX using Docxtemplater to PDF?

Tags: javascript, pdf-generation, docxtemplater

i created page to generate documents in word DOCX and  I try to generate word document using this code:

```
function loadFile(url,callback){
                PizZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url,callback);
            }
            function gen(id, dane) {
                $.ajax({
                    url:"create.php",
                    method:"post",
                    data:{id},
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                        dane.numer = data;
                        generate(dane);
                    }
                });
            }
            function generate(data) {
                loadFile("/doc.docx",function(error,content){
                    if (error) { throw error };
                    function replaceErrors(key, value) {
                        if (value instanceof Error) {
                            return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(value).reduce(function(error, key) {
                                error[key] = value[key];
                                return error;
                            }, {});
                        }
                        return value;
                    }
                    function errorHandler(error) {
                        console.log(JSON.stringify({error: error}, replaceErrors));

                        if (error.properties && error.properties.errors instanceof Array) {
                            const errorMessages = error.properties.errors.map(function (error) {
                                return error.properties.explanation;
                            }).join("\n");
                            console.log('errorMessages', errorMessages);
                        }
                        throw error;
                    }
                    var zip = new PizZip(content);
                    var doc;
                    try {
                        doc=new window.docxtemplater(zip);
                    } catch(error) {
                        errorHandler(error);
                    }
                    doc.setData(data);
                    try {
                        doc.render();
                    }
                    catch (error) {
                        errorHandler(error);
                    }
                    var out=doc.getZip().generate({
                        type:"blob",
                        mimeType: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
                    })
                    saveAs(out,"Prot "+ data.name +".docx")
                })
            }
```

Does anyone know how to convert this word document DOCX to a PDF file on this page?
Does anyone know how to convert this word document DOCX to a PDF file on this page?